# Pulling from inputText field always returns null

Tags: jsf, web

So, I'm currently working with JSF trying to create a simple project that takes input from a JSF inputText field, does something to it, and then spits it back out. Unfortunately i've reached an infuriating roadblock when trying to pull data from the inputText field. Whenever I attempt to pull from this field, it always returns null, even though there is obviously data in the field. Also, whenever I pull data from this inputText field, the field goes blank. Help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:inputText id="username" required="true"
                 binding="#{mBean.searchField}" />
    <h:button onclick="#{mBean.pull()}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function doThing(i){
            document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = i;
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="alert('clicked')" onmouseup="doThing('#{mBean.value}')">display</button><br/>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</h:body>
```

and then the backend managed bean is as follows:

```
package bean;
```

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MBean {

```
/**
 * Creates a new instance of MBean
 */
public String value;
public String otherValue;
public UIInput searchField;

public MBean() {
    System.out.println("starting mbean");
}

public String getValue() {
    System.out.println("returning first value " + value);
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String v) {
    this.value = v;
    System.out.println("setting value to " + v);
}
public void report(){
    System.out.print("SUBMIT----");
    System.out.println("value: " + value);
    System.out.println("otherValue: " + otherValue);
}
public String getOtherValue() {
    System.out.println("got " + otherValue);
    return otherValue;
}
public void pull(){
    value = (String)searchField.getValue();
    System.out.println("pulled value is " + value);
}
public void setOtherValue(String otherValue) {
    this.otherValue = otherValue;
    System.out.println("otherValue was set to " + otherValue);
}

public UIInput getSearchField() {
    return searchField;
}

public void setSearchField(UIInput searchField) {
    this.searchField = searchField;
}
```

}

I've been pulling my hair trying to figure this out for hours, so any help is very welcome. Thanks in advance,

-Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 <h:inputText id="username" required="true" immediate="true"
                  binding="#{mBean.searchField}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, I'm under time constraints so i had already chosen a different method. As soon as i get the chance, i'll test your solution so i can upvote your answer.